# Creation date of zip file

Tags: filesystems, zip, web, date

Is there any way how can I get creation date of zip file which is stored on server?
Or even better when the file was uploaded on server?

I do not have access to the server disk, I can only download that zip file.

Thanks

Comment: There's no creation date stored in the zipfile itself, but the individual files have creation dates; which isn't quite what you're looking for but might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no.  You'll need file-system access on the server itself and/or to the audit logs on the server (assuming auditing was set up) to get this information.